# how to get attribute value of div in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, attributes

I have a `div` like this:

```
<div id="1" class="2" no="3" type="4"></div>
```

i want get property `no` and `type` in ASP.net.

please help me.

Comment: does it have a tag runat="server" ?? else you cannot get it in asp.net..

Comment: No, Do not have. In addition, I add these two qualities by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Add the runat="server" attribute to the div and access the other attributes in code-behind like this: string attr = divId.Attributes["attrName"];

If you are adding the attributes with javaScript, make sure to run this code after the javaScrip has added them. Otherwise you might get a null refference exception.

Answer (score 0):

add tag `runat="server"` and then in c# `divid.yourproperty`